# Excel/VBA: Variable Value/Text into concatenate formula

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

I'm trying to do this in macro:

A cell should be filled with `=CONCATENATE("[Text]",Variable,"[Text2]")`

Variable is a number in a different case a string.

Let's say:
*Text=Hello*, *Variable* is filled with *1*, *Text2=Community*

Then it should say in the cell

```
=CONCATENATE("Hello";"1";"Community")
```

and it should be read as: **Hello1Community**

When I try `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(""Hello"",Variable,""Community"")"` then I get this:
`=CONCATENATE("Hello";Variable;"Community")`.

Sadly it is the name of the Variable but not its content. I get the **#Name?** error because the Variable is not wrapped around "".

In a different case I'm trying to put a reference to a previous sheet and cell.

In my macro I'm creating a new sheet and want to reference to it. I save the sheet's name into a variable (string). Then create a new sheet and certain cells should reference to the previous sheet.

Let's say previous sheet's name = sheet1
Cell I wanna reference to = B4

Then I want to fill the new cell with: `=sheet1!B4`

sheet1 is in a variable.

When I try `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & variable & "!B4"`, then it fills the cell with `=sheet1'!B4'`

I get the **#Name?** error because of the ' '

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you need to work out where to put double quotes:

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(""Hello"",""" & Variable & """,""Community"")"
```

In the second case, you need to work out where to put single quotes, and change the property to `Formula` instead of `FormulaR1C1`:

```
    ActiveCell.Formula = "='" & Variable & "'!B4"
```

Comment: You sir are awesome! Worked like a charm!